# Please recommend movie titles

Tags: film, research

have some projects lined up and doing research. Can you guys recommend good sounding movies of the following?

1. Boxing
2. War (civil war or early periodic war, so not as busy, think pre-machine guns)
3. Monster movie (specifically the type of monster that transforms from a human into something beast-y)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you searched previous questions? I think there's quite a bit of this already answered here.

Comment: Yes, I have searched previous questions. For boxing, layers for sound design are discussed. Also, foley, etc. But I'm looking for references, and if I can gather them in one thread that would be really helpful. I don't need only the sound design of fight scenes, but how boxing films as a whole are treated as a whole. So again, film titles, instead of technique. I have also googled, and yes there are a lot of boxing films. I purchase legally so I'd rather have the recommendations of a community than research each and every one. So same reasons for number 2, and 3. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Going for the obvious...

1. Raging Bull - one of the greatest movies of all time, which happens to be about a boxer. Fantastic use of sound throughout the film.
2. no recommendations but Glory looks exactly what you're after. TV series like War and Peace (2007) or Napoleon (2002) might have good research material (haven't seen them)
3. American Werewolf in London

   and Hulk are classics in the transformations field

Good luck!

Comment: For pre-machine gun war scenes see Kubrick's Barry Lyndon (1975) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBFpw-459VU

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in soundDesign I will assume you are doing research on sound design in films. One of my favorite films for sound design in general (and fits in a bit before your civil war era) is Master and Commander, you really need a nice 7.1 setup to get the full effect but worth a listen.

The League Of Extraordinary Gentlemen has man to beast as well lots of other great civil war era sounds as well, and is just a good movie.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry I'll do your research for you.

1. The Fighter - Here's a great video about the sound design for the film http://soundworkscollection.com/videos/thefighter
2. Glory is a great film for Civil War
3. You need to be more specific

Explain what your research is for and can help more